# Android in app-billing implementation

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm working on application which needs to implement In App-Billing payments and I was searching more info about it and find a library written by someone else and I'm curious about it. Is it good to be used and if anyone here already tried it. It seems like it's not so complicated to understand,but I just want to hear some information can I used it and is it stable enough. Here is the project code which I find :[AndroidBillingLibrary](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary).

So any suggestions / advices and information about that library is welcomed. Or anything else which will help me to understand more clearly in app-billing process in android (except the documentation in android.com) will be really great!

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: You could also look into urban airship if you dont want to write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very clearly states on the tin: 'This library is a very early release and it should not be used as production code'. So if you want to use it, you will have to understand how it works to be able to fix it when it breaks. You might as well write your own.

Read the official documentation, study the dungeons sample, try to understand and if you get stuck, post specific questions. Otherwise, just hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: Actually I got more familiar with in app-purchase after the end of the day,so I guess I will write my own implementation. Thanks anyway for the answer!